# Unable to import a .bacpac created by Azure SQL to local SSMS

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

This is the error I get

> Import bacpac: Could not import package.
> Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The login already has an account under a different user name.
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
> CREATE USER [azdouser] FOR LOGIN [azdouser];

Comment: error message is clear

Comment: What do you mean by "local SSMS"? What database are you importing it to? Did you verify that login doesn't have an account under a different username?

Comment: I am new to using database so pardon my ignorance....I am using New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $MyResourceGroupName -ServerName $MyServerName `
  -DatabaseName $MyDatabaseName -StorageKeytype $MyStorageKeytype -StorageKey $MyStorageKey -AuthenticationType 'sql' -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
  -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password to create a .bacpac which I want to make sure is able to generate the same db so I am trying to import the .bacpac to the same db server using SSMS

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import a bacpac to a SQL Server (on-premises) instance using SSMS (Import Data-Tier Application option). I remember a user that had the same error (Msg 15063) and I provided a possible solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753230/recieving-create-user-error-when-attempt-to-import-bacpac-from-blob-storage-to-s/57756008#57756008) Stack Overflow thread.